# How can I calculate the number of matches of a jakarta.ejb.ScheduleExpression within a time interval in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm working on a Java project and need to calculate the number of matches of a `jakarta.ejb.ScheduleExpression` within a specific time interval. I've already written an implementation that generates the ScheduleExpression from an JSON-Resultset. However, now I need to calculate the number of matches the Cron Schedule would match in a time interval.
Here is an Example of the JSON Object:

```
        {
        "dayOfWeek": "Mon,Wed",
        "hour": "15",
        "month": null,
        "dayOfMonth": "*",
        "year": null,
        "second": 0/5,
        "minute": "00"
        }
```

Could anyone provide guidance or suggest a more efficient approach to achieve this? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.